# Text file parsing - how can I search for a specific string and return whole line?

Tags: c#

e.g txt file has following entries say :

```
england is cold country
India is poor country
england is cold country
england is cold country
India is poor country
english county cricket season.
```

now i want to search this txt file for a string "england" and return the entire line containing this string. How can i do it using C sharp language ?

Answer (score 2):

I would consider two approaches, for large file (megabytes) and for relatively small.

## Large File

If file is large and contains megabytes of data: use stream reader, read file untile EndOfLine, analize just readed string

```
string pattern = "england";
IList<string> result = new List<string>();
using (var reader = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt")) 
{
    string currentLine;
    while ((currentLine= reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {
        if (currentLine.Contains(pattern)
        {
            // if you do not need multiple lines and just the first one
            // just break from the loop (break;)            
            result.Add(currentLine);
        }
    }
}
```

## Small file

If a file is small you can use helper which returns all file content as array of strings - ([File.ReadAllLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) string per line and then use LINQ to search for substring. if you are using `.NET 4` or newer you can leverage new helper ([File.ReadLines()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readlines%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) which does not read entire file and does read as deffered operation.

.NET 2.0 - 3.5:

```
string pattern = "england";
IEnumerable<string> result = File.ReadAllLines()
                                 .Where(l => l.Contains(pattern));
```

.NET4 - 4.5:

```
string pattern = "england";
IEnumerable<string> result = File.ReadLines()
                                 .Where(l => l.Contains(pattern));
```

if you need just the first line use `.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Contains(pattern))` instead of `Where(l => l.Contains(pattern))`

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use
>   ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before
>   the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must
>   wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access
>   the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files,
>   ReadLines can be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, here one challenge that i am facing is what to write in "Console.Writeline();" so that i get all the lines on the console that matches the desired string.

Comment: so what is the challenge with writing to the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like. If you want to return all lines with "england" you need to create a list of strings and return this.

```
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines("FILEPATH"))
    {
    if(line.contains("england"))
       return line;
    }
    return string.empty;
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for providing resolution, her one thing more i want to ask, can i have unique lines and unique counts using Hashset count method. I have tried this code but it is not working :

Answer (score 0):

1) Read All Lines. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx

2) Create a List of strings to populate matches

3) Loop or linq the lines and look for match using IndexOf(matchstring) > -1

4) Return result