# How to search for a string in a text file?

Tags: c#, search, stream, text-files

How do I search for a string in a text file line. And if found save it as a string variable...
I need an example if possible. I have tried to do it but couldn't do it. I can't post what I have tried because I'm stupid and deleted it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this page thats explain how search for a specific string and return whole line.

Its can help you...

See the link:

[Text file parsing - how can I search for a specific string and return whole line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023282/text-file-parsing-how-can-i-search-for-a-specific-string-and-return-whole-line)

Thaks.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I'll be here with an edit soon! Cheers! :)